# Why does Sphinx not document my class?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a module with 4 classes

```
class B(object):
    """Docstring for B."""
    pass

class C(B):
    """Docstring for C."""
    pass

class D(B):
    """Docstring for D."""
    pass

class A(object):
    """Docstring for A."""
    c = C()
    d = D()
```

Only class A is made accessible in the API, together with its attributes c and d (instances of C and D)

The Sphinx generated documentation only shows classes A, C and D

Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: This Python code is not valid. What is your Sphinx setup? Please provide a minimal example!

Comment: I had the same problem once and had to use: make clean before e.g. make html. Might ofc not be it this time.

Comment: I've now added a minimal example. I'm embarrassed to say this does work, so it's back to my real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with Sphinx. The problem was that I had a line of code between the "class" line and the docstring. Now that that I have removed that it works perfectly - embarrassed